# Allow introspection on my D-Bus system service

Tags: dbus

After having spend a bit time on understanding how D-Bus Session and System buses are working, I'm now focusing on allowing people to use and introspect my service in order to allow anyone to implement easily features using my service.

I have then wrote the following configuration file that I placed in my `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
 <busconfig>
  <policy user="root">
    <allow own="org.zedroot.Test" />
    <allow send_destination="org.zedroot.Test" />
  </policy>
  <policy context="default">
    <allow send_destination="org.zedroot.Test"
           send_interface="org.zedroot.Test" />
    <allow send_destination="org.zedroot.Test"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" />
    <allow send_destination="org.zedroot.Test"
           send_interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" />
  </policy>
</busconfig>
```

But using d-feet I can see my service but not introspect it (I don't see anything inside my service: no methods, signals or properties).

Could anyone please help me ?

Comment: Do you have a introspection format file? A XML file which describes your interface?

Comment: No I haven't. The file pasted in the question is the only one I put in that folder. To be more precise I'm working with a C++ application using the dbus-cxx library.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference.

The following should be enough to allow introspection of your service:

```
.
.
<!-- Allow introspect -->
<policy context="default">
  <allow send_destination="org.zedroot.Test"/>
</policy>
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

After a reboot of my computer it's now working.

Comment: Then you just needed to restart dbus-daemon?

Comment: Probably, not sure.